# R Optimize issues

Tags: r, optimization

I have written a function `bs.pp` that calculates the Black Scholes value of a Put Option.

```
    bs.pp <- function (Price, Strike, sigma, texp, int) {
  d1=(1 / (sigma*sqrt(texp)))*(log(Price/Strike)+(int+(sigma^2)/2)*texp)
  d2=d1-sigma*sqrt(texp)
  Strike*pnorm(-d2)*exp(-int*texp)-Price*pnorm(-d1)}
```

Which seems to work well

```
> bs.pp(1000,1000,.2,1,.02)
[1] 69.35905
> bs.pp(1000,900,.25,1,.02)
[1] 46.15609
```

I am now trying to utilize the R `optimize` function to calculate the inverse of the function when we know (`Price`, `Strike`, `texp`, `int`) and the result of the function but not `sigma`.

I tried to do this as follows

```
gg <- function(Price, Strike, sigma, texp, int, PutPrice){(bs.pp(Price, Strike, sigma, texp, int) - PutPrice)^2}
xmin <- optimize(gg, c(0,1), tol = 0.0001, Price = 1000, Strike = 1000, texp = 1, int = 0.02, PutPrice = 69.4)
xmin$minimum
```

Which returns the error

```
Error in optimize(gg, c(0, 1), tol = 1e-04, Price = 1000, Strike = 1000,  : 
  'xmin' not less than 'xmax'
```

Interestingly if I run the following (NOTE "int = 0.02" replaced with just "0.02" in the optimize line)

```
gg <- function(Price, Strike, sigma, texp, int, PutPrice){(bs.pp(Price, Strike, sigma, texp, int) - PutPrice)^2}
xmin <- optimize(gg, c(0,1), tol = 0.0001, Price = 1000, Strike = 900, texp = 1, 0.02, PutPrice = 46.2)
xmin$minimum
```

I get the correct answer

```
[1] 0.2501474
```

And to prove that wasn't just a fluke

```
gg <- function(Price, Strike, sigma, texp, int, PutPrice){(bs.pp(Price, Strike, sigma, texp, int) - PutPrice)^2}
xmin <- optimize(gg, c(0,1), tol = 0.0001, Price = 1000, Strike = 1000, texp = 1, 0.02, PutPrice = 69.4)
xmin$minimum
```

returns the correct answer also

```
[1] 0.2001055
```

Any ideas?
I've tried moving the arguments of the function around so  that `sigma` is first but that doesn't seem to make any difference.

Just FYI my end function was going to be the following, which I'm sure can be written more elegantly

```
bs.piv <- function(Price, Strike, texp, intr, PutPrice){
  optfunc <- function(P, S, sigma, t, i, PP){(bs.pp(Price, Strike, sigma, texp, intr) - PutPrice)^2}
  xmin <- optimize(optfunc, c(0,1), tol = 0.0001, P=Price, S=Strike, t=texp, i=intr, PP=PutPrice)
  xmin$minimum}
```

Comment: @Alex A how did you do that?

Comment: @Alex A edit the text so for example bs.pp no longer shows as 'normal text'

Comment: Surround it in backticks \`like this\`. It's inline code formatting. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for more info.

Comment: @ Alex A Thank You. I'd actually looked at format options but must have missed that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Naming all your arguments is usually a good idea, especially when working with the `...` argument. It fixes the problem in this case:

```
xmin <- optimize(f = gg, interval = c(0,1), tol = 0.0001, Price = 1000, Strike = 1000, texp = 1, int = 0.02, PutPrice = 69.4)
```

EDIT: as @Roland explained, `interval` is matched by `int`, so this is one example for the dangers of partial matching of arguments in R.

Comment: Thanks David much appreciated. I had actually wondered whether using "int" was the problem but my fear was that it was confusing "int" with an "integer" command but couldn't find one. I even tried changing "int" to "inte" and it still didnt work. Of course "inte" still gets confused with "interval". Much Appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to @David H's answer, which provides the solution of naming the `interval` argument, here is an explanation:

This is a consequence of partial matching of arguments. See [the language definition](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.pdf) section 4.3.2 for details. In brief, the matching works in three steps:

1.) Exact name matches are searched for between the supplied arguments and optimize'  arguments. E.g., `interval` would be matched to `interval` here.

2.) Partial name matches are searched for between the supplied arguments and optimize' arguments. E.g., `int` would be matched to `interval` here.

3.) Positional matching occurs. "If there is a ‘...’ argument, it will take up the remaining arguments, tagged or not." And `...` is used by `optimize` to pass arguments to the function specified in `f`.

So, step 2 takes away your `int` argument because partial matching occurs before positional matching.

Comment: Thanks Roland much appreciated. I had actually wondered whether using "int" was the problem but my fear was that it was confusing "int" with an "integer" command but couldn't find one. I even tried changing "int" to "inte" and it still didnt work. Of course "inte" still gets confused with "interval". I will definitely be more careful about naming all function inputs in the future. Much Appreciated.